# How to remove scroolling functionality in react

Tags: reactjs

I need to remove the scroll bar from my react app

I have used the overflow hidden method but it doesn't work,
also, i have used react-remove scrollbar but due to lack of proper documentation I m not able to
do it.

Comment: Without including an example of the markup/React that is scrollable, this is pretty much unanswerable.

Comment: the whole home page is scrollable just any web page and i want that scroll bar to remove and completly in functionable